Access web server behind a gateway
I'm trying to connect to a web server behind a gateway. I can connect from the gateway to the web server (user@gateway$ wget web-server-url returns the index.html).
I can't connect to the web server from my computer outside this network, I can only SSH into the gateway. I would like to access the web server on my browser from my computer.

[My computer] --- ssh ---- [Gateway] ---- http request --- [web server]

I don't have admin rights on the gateway or the web server, only on my computer.
I don't think port forwarding is the solution here. As far as I understand, I need SSH access to the web server, which I don't have. If I'm incorrect, please let me know.
Any way to solve this?
Update to answer some comments: My computer is running Ubuntu 22.04. The gateway is running Linux, not sure what flavour, but I don't have rights to install anything on the gateway or the web server. I have root on my computer.
I do have SSH to the gateway, and I have created tunnel to other servers behind the gateway that I also have ssh access. But for the web server I don't have SSH access.

Do you have ssh access to the gateway? In theory you could use a SSH tunnel from your computer to the gateway, but some more information (what OSes?) might be needed for a fuller answer.

Do you have the ability to install software (in your own account, not systemwide) on the gateway? If so, you could install a web (HTTP) proxy or reverse-proxy that could do what you need. In fact if the gateway already has Python on it, you might be able to use the existing Python environment to create a simple proxy. Without admin privs, you won't be able to make it listen on port 80 or 443, so you might have to run it on, say, port 8080 and you'll have to specify the port number in the URL you give your browser.

Use ssh tunneling on the gateway to tunnel/redirect any connection from port 8080 on the WAN/public IP address of the gateway to port 8080 on one of the behind-the-gateway servers you have access to. On that server's port 8080, run a reverse proxy that proxies all HTTP requests to the web server. You could use nginx or Python or any number of solutions to act as the reverse proxy. Or, if you want something that runs only on the gateway, you'll have to tell us what you do have access to on the gateway: Python? nginx? Apache? Docker? netcat (nc) or socat?

I suspect a 'simple' SSH tunnel would work, I have just about enough information on your setup to figure out what'd potentially work so some testing is in order.
On your computer - you want to run a ssh tunnel to the gateway
ssh -D 8888 gateway (you can use any port)
On firefox you'd set it up like so

On chrome and other browsers you'd need to set up a proxy systemwide.
Then just access the webpage with the web server URL on the browser you've set up
